# Difference between eclipse 3.8 and 3.8.1?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

What are the major differences between eclipse 3.8.0 and 3.8.1?

Eclipse 3.8: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8-201206081200/

Eclipse 3.8.1: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8.1-201209141540/

I could not find any related notes present in above links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three Eclipse releases a year. A major one in june (for instance Eclipse 3.8.0) then two service releases (for instance 3.8.1 and 3.8.2) respectively in september and february.

There is generally no major new feature in service releases which tends to be more stable versions with only bug fixes.

I have never seen any change log for the overall Eclipse project releases. I think there are so many projects that this is almost impossible/useless to list all changes of all projects.

There may have some changelog for certain components, but this is done on a per project basis.
 
Now all changes should be tracked on the [Eclipse bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/), so if you are interested on a specific component this may be of interest.